# left join multiple table take too long time , below query .

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

```
SELECT DISTINCT(j.id), 
            j.first_name,
            j.middle_name,
            j.last_name,
            ald.email AS email_address,
            j.photo_file,
            j.unique_id,
            el.title AS education_title, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(tjt.training_title) SEPARATOR ', ') AS training_title, CONCAT(j.vdc_municipality, ', ', d.district) AS district_name, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(tms.description) SEPARATOR ', ') AS description
FROM tbl_jobseeker j
LEFT JOIN district d ON j.district=d.district_id
LEFT JOIN zone z ON z.id=d.zone_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_jobseeker_training tjt ON 
                j.id=tjt.jobseeker_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_jobseeker_skill tjs ON 
                j.id=tjs.jobseeker_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_master_skills tms ON 
                tms.id=tjs.skill
LEFT JOIN tbl_jobseeker_education tjee ON 
                tjee.jobseeker_id=j.id
LEFT JOIN tbl_education_level tel ON
                tel.id=tjee.education_degree
LEFT JOIN tbl_jobseeker_employment tje ON
                tje.jobseeker_id=j.id
LEFT JOIN tbl_jobseeker_skilloccupationdetails tjso ON
                tjso.jobseeker_id=j.id
LEFT JOIN tbl_education_level el ON tjso.high_degree=el.id
LEFT JOIN tbl_apply_this_job taj ON taj.jobseeker_id=j.id
LEFT JOIN tbl_vacancydetails tvd ON tvd.id=taj.job_id
LEFT JOIN applicant_login_detail ald ON
                    ald.applicant_id=j.id AND ald.type=1
WHERE j.share_resume=1 AND training_title IS NOT NULL
```

this query takes a long time to execute, is there any way to make fast . it takes more than 1 minute to execute. I have spent lots of time to solve this issue but i found nothing.

Comment: use EXPLAIN To find out where you Need an index and add them to your tables

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function on a column, it's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT` and applies to the whole selected rows. Skip those redundant parentheses and simply write `SELECT DISTINCT j.id, 
            j.first_name, ...` to make the query clearer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Just use hints, it will help the query to be executed as you want. Check here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimizer-hints.html
2. Create indexes.
3. Create temporary tables in order to reduce the amount of data that is being stored in memory.

Also, do you really need the DISTINCT? The distinct instruction sorts your table's data, which will show down everything.